# Create a mail template in Magento by SQL script?

Tags: database, magento, magento-1.4, email-templates

is it possible to create a mail template directly by running some SQL script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to transactional e-mails, yes

If you look in the installer scripts in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade
```

you can find samples of SQL statements used to update existing templates.

```
mysql4-upgrade-0.6.2-0.7.0.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.7.2-0.7.3.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.3-0.8.4.php
```

and

```
app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/sql/contacts_setup/mysql14-upgrade
```

shows insert and update SQL statements

```
mysql4-install-0.7.1.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.7.1-0.7.2.php
```